# Mac OS X application slows down when its window has not focus

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, osx-yosemite

I am developing a MAC OS X application with SWIFT and ObjC using XCode 6.1.
The application is a server and it uses a CFSocketRef in the main thread run loop.

When the application window has not the focus on it the application slows down and the server receives the messages from the client with delay.

Is this normal (an app with no focus slows down)? 
If it is normal is there a way to set the main thread priority so that if the app has no focus it continues running in the same way?

Comment: It's probably because of "App Nap" in Yosemite. It seems like you can prevent this by using `beginActivityWithOptions`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html But I can't give a real answer as I've never actually used this in my apps.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will read the document at the link you posted!

Comment: Thank you Eric! It was App Nap I have added beginActivityWithOptions to my code.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel like it, you can post your own answer to this question, explaining what you did to make it work. I'm sure it will be helpful for others, and it certainly will be helpful for me to have a working example. :)

Answer (score 4):

In my controller class I have added in the `awakeFromNib` function the `beginActivityWithOptions` and than in the `applicationWillTerminate` the `endActivity` like the following

```
class ConsoleController: NSObject
{
  var process : NSProcessInfo?
  var activity: NSObjectProtocol?
  override func awakeFromNib()
  {
    process = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
    activity = process!.beginActivityWithOptions(NSActivityOptions.UserInitiated, reason: "Good")
  }
  func applicationWillTerminate(notification: NSNotification)
  {
    process!.endActivity(activity!)
  }
}
```

Comment: Swift5: activity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: .userInitiated, reason: "Good")